# how to fetch data from sql server and display on webpage in the form of Bar chart or pie chart using asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace Authentication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult CreateBar()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "bar",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");

        }

        public ActionResult CreatePie()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "pie",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }

        public ActionResult CreateLine()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "line",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here, I am displaying hard coded data on a webpage in form of charts but I want to dynamically fetch the data from database and display on webpage in the form of graphs. Can someone please help me in this using MVC5?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace Authentication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult CreateBar()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "bar",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");

        }

        public ActionResult CreatePie()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "pie",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }

        public ActionResult CreateLine()
        {
            //Create bar chart
            var chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "line",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 ", "50", "30 ", "70" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "70", "90", "110" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is extremely vague - if you want to display chart on webpage you can use JavaScript / jQuery plugin such as flot, Chart.js etc.

Comment: Thank you James for your advise . I will give a try

Comment: Have a look at my answer here if would like to use flot - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636079/general-approach-to-visualize-sql-ce-data-using-flot-js-in-asp-net-mvc-4/24706904#24706904

Comment: iam using Charts.js plugin to display the data . thanks for quick response. I can display the data now .